# iText compatibility issue

Tags: java, itext, bouncycastle

I am trying to set password protection to a PDF, using:

- JRE7
- iText ver 5.2.1
- bcprov jdk16 1.46
- bctsp jdk16 1.46
- bcmail jdk16 1.40

I experience the following issues:

1. The `PdfReader`, `PdfStamper` and `PdfWriter` class are not getting read.
2. If I change the version of iText to 5.3.2 then the previous issue is getting solved but while execution I am getting this error:

   > ClassNotFound org/bouncycastle/asn1/ANS1Encodable

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use BouncyCastle version 1.49. You probably don't use Maven or Gradle or anything similar, but you manually add jars to your lib folder. If you use Maven, then it will automatically find all the dependencies for you, with all the right versions. Maven makes your life a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks AVG, I am using Eclipse IDE, as you have said I need to add the jar files externally. The problem is I don't have download access, so is there any other way round to solve this issue.

Comment: *"The `PdfReader`, `PdfStamper` and `PdfWriter` class are not getting read."* - What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that all your jars are compatible. As you can see in this [`pom.xml`](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/5.3.2/itext/pom.xml), iText 5.3.2 expects BouncyCastle **1.47**. I previously wrote 1.49, that was a typo.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.47</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.47</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

You *must* [download](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle) the correct versions of the BouncyCastle jars and include them in your project. If you cannot download the correct versions, then your problem cannot be solved. There is no other way around it.